# Setting New Default Operator Preset?

Tags: customization, operator

I'm using Blender 2.8!

I've created an operator preset for importing models. It's simple, just import everything with z-forward instead of backwards. Is there anyway to make this default? Every time I import something I have to set it again.

Thank you for your time!